# AMP HTML timeout event to open/show lightbox after some time

Tags: amp-html

Is it possible for publishers to show popups for signup/offers using AMP-Lightbox component after a time delay (say avg time on site - 5s)? Any solution with amp-bind / amp-animation that could work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with amp-lightbox. The reason is that delayed popups are a  bad user experience which goes against AMPs ideals. If you absolutely must do this, you can achieve this via CSS animations by fading-in an element after a certain delay.

Comment: Can we use `setTimeout(function(){` in `AMP` pages? thank you in advance...